# JasperReports fonts

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to export the Japanese report in PDF. Report font must be Tahoma. So I set the report font as "Tahoma". Initially it thrown like "tahoma" not available to JVM, I have placed the tahoma.ttf as jar in classpath. After that, When I execute, For Tahoma, it doesn't support, pdf encode= "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H" option.

Error is like:
Usupported encoding: "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H"

PDF font used is "HeiseiKakuGo-W5"

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Did you set pdfEncoding and pdfEncoding attributes? Did you check your report in iReport (via preview function)?

Comment: You can see this article about fonts at Win platform: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134. Another info about fonts with East Asian support: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts.html

Comment: Hi alex,Yes, I have set the pdf encoding as "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H". Since this is for Japanese.

Comment: You can try set font options: <font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>. Arail - is the sample font

Comment: I have also tried with Identity-H, same error happens..

Comment: Did you view your report in iReport with help of internal viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use pdfEncoding or isPdfEmbedded. These attributes were deprecated years ago. Use Font Extensions. They were introduced to solve exactly this problem. They'll let you generate the PDF as you are attempting to do. If you Google "jasperreports font extensions" you should find the information that you need.

Comment: Hi, thnks vry much for the reply. I have other question as below: half of the Report is getting generated in vertical (japanese). any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be the choice of "Identity-H" or "Identity-V" for the PDF Encoding in the definition of the Font Extension to set horizontal or vertical.

Comment: It is set as UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H (Japanese). The intersting thing is, the same jrxml is working very fine in other environment.

Comment: Also, its not half of the report, the parameters maintained in our db, is passed to report through plugin, tat japanese parameters only displaying in vertical, any suggestions idea?