# How to display unicodes in jasper-reports on windows

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I have some reports which I need to be shown using uni-codes in jasper-reports. But, when those reports are shown in Windows I can't see characters properly instead report shows boxes for characters, So, what is the proper way to show uni-codes on windows using jasper-reports?

Comment: Can you just tell me the language you are rendering on Jasper reports?

Comment: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/unicode/index.html

Comment: Hindi and Sinhala-(Main language in Sri Lanka)

Comment: It's a font question, but it really has no relation to Unicode. It should be re-tagged to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a font which cannot support the characters you are using. You need to use [font extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499751/jasper-reports-fonts) to specify an appropriate font.