# Regarding Tamil Reports Issues in iReport (JasperReports)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *iReport Designer 4.0.1* and generating the *tamil* reports, while I'm generating the reports most of the *tamil* characters are not supported.

In report preview I'm getting the exact character what I am expecting but while I am saving that as PDF i am not getting the exact character what i expected.

In my `.jrxml` file the values are correct but in pdf it's not displaying the exact characters.

I am using the *Arial Unicode.TTF* for tamil fonts.

I am working in Linux platform.

Please help me how to solve the issues.

Comment: Did you tried adding the Arial tamil font in the jasper report fonts jar file. Else you will see in the internal preview, but not in the pdf output. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Font extensions, font extensions. The answer is always font extensions. @Thanigaivel is correct, but his answer doesn't include much detail. Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499751/jasper-reports-fonts

Comment: First i thank you for response. I tried with Arial tamil font also but i am getting the same issue what i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any resource bundle which could be directly referred in text field properties using `$R{first.name}` where `first.name` is a property in properties file.
Let me know if this helps.

Also, please check if unicode fonts jar is created and classpath is set in ireport.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOR TAMIL REPORTS AND PDF IN TAMIL**

I used LE-ET-Ramya(etramya.ttf) Tamil Font For Tamil Reports

set `pdfFontName="etramya.ttf"` and `isPdfEmbedded ="true"` for user tamil field $F{TamilName}

we can store data in table and retrieve directly from table and display reports in pdf/html/ODF file in tamil is working.

in servlet to work for particular jrxml field set pdffontname with font store location path
eg:

```
pdfFontName="font/etramya.ttf"
```

To download font http://www.elcot.in/tamilfonts_download_list.php

any query come forward free to ask

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

EG: -

SOLUTION FOR TAMIL REPORTS AND PDF IN TAMIL

I used LE-ET-Ramya(etramya.ttf) Tamil Font For Tamil Reports

set pdfFontName="etramya.ttf" and isPdfEmbedded ="true" for user tamil field $F{TamilName}

we can store data in table and retrieve directly from table and display reports in pdf/html/ODF file in tamil is working.

pdfFontName="etramya.ttf"

http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/answers/tamilreports.jrxml
http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/answers/tamilreportswithparameter.jrxml